# How can I fetch a list of topics on a Yammer Network?

Tags: yammer

I want to fetch a list of all the Topics that have been used on a Yammer Network. I have an app set up and can use the API fine, but there's no endpoint specifically for getting a list of Topics.

I could use [the `search.json`](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/searchjson) endpoint, with no query, which will get me 20 at a time, but along with Messages, Users, Files, Groups, Pages... which seems messy. Is there no other way?

I'm also *assuming* that this is only fetching data from a single Yammer Network - if I was on several, is it possible to restrict to only one network?

Comment: This is a very valid request. I'm also trying to implement an internal app focused on topics, but don't have a way to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you have admin rights you can use the API to call the [Data Export API](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/data-export-api) which will return topics.csv.

Topics themselves are not a heavily used feature in Yammer since organisations normally work in groups and despite hashtags being popular on Twitter they don't get used a lot in Yammer. The Topic feature is cleaner than hashtags in messages, but again only a subset of power users put the effort into adding topics so your mileage may vary. Yammer tends to revolve around groups.

Comment: Thanks Brian. It's for a client that wants to use topics in a particular way. I've just used the search endpoint for now; just seems odd there's no way to restrict a search to a single type of entity.